# Linux CentOS installation will not start in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos

I downloaded CentOS 8 ISO (That had dvd1 postfix). This is biggest image so I guess this has everything.

I am installing this on VirtualBox 6.1, it boots up, I select install but all I get is this blank screen for ever and nothing moves.

[image]

I tried the `Test this media and install` option as well but same results.

My VM settings is this:

[image]

Comment: FYI: CentOS is end of life (CentOS, not CentOS 8).  Do you have the choice of a non-graphical install?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that my system doesn't meet minimum requirements for linux. I have 4th i7 processor but it doesn't seem to have virtualization features.

I did have Virtualization option enabled in BIOS but apparently it still comes short.

How I come to find out and the best way to diagnose this is to install VMWare Player and try setting up similar VM there. It typically has the results but it puts our the exact error message instead of just stalling.

In my case the error was:

[image]

I also saw some people disabled all services starting from Hyper-V and documentation says it should resolve the problem. When  these services are disabled, the VM don't use them (bypass) but it in my case the VM still didn't work.

[image]

**Update**

I found a way to run the VM. Basically you turn of the hypervisor via the following command and reboot.

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Now Linux VM installation does run and I guess this needs to be off.

You can turn it back on via:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

But linux VM will not run now, so I guess you have to keep it off.

sources: [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/run-hyper-v-and-vmware-virtual-machines-on-windows-10) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35812945/841330)

Also I checked on Intel site and Virtualization technology is supported on my i7-4xxx processor but it still complains. Maybe someone else has a better answer.