# My processor supports Intel Virtualization technology, but why Linux VM still complains that it doesn't?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, hyper-v, hypervisor

I posted [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1609971/167207) because CentOS or RedHat Linux VM will not install either in VirtualBox or VMWare Player. The later was specific in error that my computer doesn't support requirements (Hyper-V or Device Credentials Gard (DCG) enabled.

I had to disable Hyper-V to come around but my processor is an Intel i7-4790 that supports Intel Virtualization technology per Intel’s website.

So why do I have to disable it to make the VM work?

I am interested because when I installed Xamarin, it was also complaining something of the order that virtualization is missing which is suppose to have better performance for phone simulator.

So is there a way I can enable Hyper-V and still run the VMs? Isn't the whole purpose of it to run VMs better?

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you run?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 Version 1909

Comment: Simplest solution is to install 20H2 allowing you to use VirtualBox and VMWare Workstation with Hyper-V enabled. Your accepted answer requires you to upgrade to 2004 at least (my recommendation would be 20H2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So is there a way I can enable Hyper-V and still run the VMs?

Yes, we'll get to that in a moment.

> Isn't the whole purpose of it to run VMs better?

No. Hyper-V is *Microsoft's hypervisor implementation*. It *competes* with VirtualBox and VMware's hypervisors. Hyper-V only "runs VMs better" if you actually use a Hyper-V-based VM, not a VirtualBox or VMware VM.

The way hardware virtualisation extensions work, they provide exclusive access to one hypervisor at a time. So you can use one of, and *only one of*, Hyper-V, VirtualBox or VMware at a time. You can have multiple VMs running, but they must all be using the same hypervisor.

Now, this introduces a problem because once enabled Hyper-V is always "running", and it is relatively cumbersome to disable. Also, some newer Windows security features require the Hyper-V hypervisor to be running. So what Microsoft has done is introduce the Windows Hypervisor Platform, which allows VirtualBox and VMware VMs to run on top of the Hyper-V hypervisor instead of the VirtualBox or VMware native hypervisors.

So instead of:

- VMware Player/Workstation, running on
- VMware hypervisor, running on
- Hardware virtualisation extensions

you have:

- VMware Player/Workstation, running on
- Windows Hypervisor Platform/Hyper-V, running on
- Hardware virtualisation extensions

Note that running on top of the Windows Hypervisor Platform, at least in the case of VMware, is considerably slower than the native VMware hypervisor at this time. If you don't need Hyper-V for other reasons, you're still best off using the specific native hypervisors for now.

It looks like Xamarin runs on top of Hyper-V, so you do need Hyper-V enabled. But that means you'll suffer a performance impact on VirtualBox and VMware VMs, and will also need Windows Hypervisor Platform enabled too.

---

> So is there a way I can enable Hyper-V and still run the VMs?

With the Windows Hypervisor Platform, *yes*. But this must be enabled separately from Hyper-V itself, as it is considered a separate feature:

[image: Windows Features dialog screenshot]

Also note in the [VMware kb article](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/76918) referenced in your error message, that the minimum version requirements for Windows and VMware to work with Windows Hypervisor Platform are quite recent - at time of writing, Windows 10 Version 2004 is the minimum supported version. Make sure you at least meed those version requirements.

| Hyper-V state | Windows Hypervisor Platform state | VBox/VMware supported |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Disabled | N/A | Yes |
| Enabled | Disabled | No |
| Enabled | Enabled | Yes |

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful. I would look into exactly what was Xamarin saying because I didn't dig into that at that time but my hyper-v (by default) was enabled then. I guess I could enable/disable with the command line `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off/auto` when I am using Xamarin or VM. But give your explanation, I would stick with native, don't really need Hyper-V for VirtualBox and VMWare-Player.

Comment: @zar The long term hope is that the Hyper-V/WHP implementation and VBox/VMware integration matures to the point that we can fully drop the native hypervisors and just use WHP for everything without any negative impact. But it's still early days; I'd check back in 3-5 years and see where things are at then. Of course, you can still use it now, but for now the performance tradeoff is not negligible. Native Hyper-V by itself performs fine.

Comment: One thing I am a bit confused is the last part. As I have asked in the linked question, VirtualBox and VMWare doesn't even run Linux VM when Hyper-V is enabled - why is that? You mentioned it would less optimal at this time (slower) but then it doesn't even run! So its like totally broken at this time?

Comment: And I haven't tried your last part but you are suggesting VirtualBox and VMWare could run those Linux VM without disabling Hyper-V if I turn off `Windows Hypervisor Platform` in _Turn On or Off Windows Features_?

Comment: @zar *If* you have Hyper-V disabled, they should run. *If* you have Hyper-V enabled, you must **also** have Windows Hypervisor Platform **enabled** to run VBox or VMware VMs. You should also make sure you have the most recent Windows and VBox/VMware version installed. Note that changing any of these features requires a restart to take effect. If you have Hyper-V enabled but WHP disabled, nothing else will run.

Comment: @zar If it's still unclear, I've added a table to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @Bob - Might point out that your answer requires 2004 or newer.  VMWare Workstation support is a great deal more stable with Hypervisor Platform than VirtualBox.  Additionally, Windows Sandbox has been known to cause issues if it’s enabled.

Comment: Well I tried the combinations you outlined in the table and unfortunately it broke both VirtualBox and VMWare. I turned them on and off using the _Turn Windows features on or off_ dialog and that seems to broke even though I restored the original settings. Turn on or off _Windows Hypervisor Platform_ had no impact. I then even tried _Virtual Machine Platform_ still no impact. But now my VMs doesn't even run in any case...hmm..

Comment: @zar As Ramhound has pointed out, you really should update to the latest version of Windows if you want to use WHP, as it is in fairly active development - 1909 is too old. That said, if you turn off Hyper-V entirely, you should be back to the state where VBox/VMware use their native hypervisors. (Virtual Machine Platform is for WSL2 support, and similarly depends on Hyper-V/conflicts with other hypervisors.)

Comment: I did upgrade to 20H2 and still had to disable hyper-v, at least now my VM is working so not going to experiment with it anymore.

Comment: @zar Along the same lines, you also need a very recent version of VMware - 15.5.5 or 16.x - to use WHP with it. Requirements are [here](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/76918).